# XGboost - different AUC score when using R and Python

Tags: python, r, xgboost, auc

I had a project in R which I used XGboost in R and got AUC of 74%.
I needed to transfer the project to python, I used the same dataframes: train and test as I used in R.
I used XGboost (XGBClassifier from xgboost) with the same hyper parameters I used in R and got AUC of 62%.
I get the its not exactly the same implementation as the R version and not the same seed but the difference is too big to be a coincidence.

The only thing I can think of is that maybe that implementation doesn't handle missing values which I have (but XGboost algorithm supposed to used them and not disregard).

what am I doing wrong? Any ideas on how I can fix that? How can I check if the algorithm disregard missing values?

My code - python:

```
.....

'params': {
        'min_child_weight': [1],
        'learning_rate': [0.05],
        'n_estimators': [300],
        'gamma': [0],
        'subsample': [1],
        'colsample_bytree': [0.8],
        'max_depth': [15],
        'booster': ['gbtree'],
        'silent': [True],
        'missing': [np.nan],
        'max_delta_step': [10],
        'colsample_bylevel': [0.8],
        'scale_pos_weight':[1],
        'reg_alpha': [0],
        'reg_lambda': [0.5],

......

model = XGBClassifier()

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=folds, shuffle=True, random_state=11)

gridSearch = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid =params, scoring='roc_auc', n_jobs=1,
cv=skf.split(xTrain, yTrain), verbose=3)

gridSearch.fit(xTrain, yTrain[target])
yPred = gridSearch.predict(xTest)

predictions = [round(value) for value in yPred]

# evaluate predictions
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(yTest, predictions, pos_label=1)
print(metrics.auc(fpr, tpr))
```

My code - R:

```
Grid <- expand.grid(nrounds = 300,
                    eta = 0.05,
                    max_depth = 15,
                    gamma = 0,
                    colsample_bytree=0.8,
                    min_child_weight=1,
                    subsample=1)



set.seed(15)


ctrl2 <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                      number = 10,
                      returnData = TRUE,
                      savePredictions = "all",
                      classProbs = TRUE,
                      summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                      selectionFunction = "best",
                      allowParallel = TRUE)

classifier <- train(x = smote_train[,-1],y = smote_train[,1], method = 'xgbTree',tuneGrid = Grid,trControl = ctrl2,metric = "ROC")


prediction <- predict(classifier, newdata= test_set[,-1],'prob')



library(classifierplots)

a <- test_set

a$y[a$readmmited=="yes"] <- 1
a$y[a$readmmited=="no"] <- 0
classifierplots(a$y, prediction$yes)
```

Comment: First, give a code example. Currently we can't know the implementation of ROCc AUC you are using. Did you build your own function? Are you using an imported one?

Comment: @Eran Moshe I have added the code.

Comment: First, I need to see the R code so I can compare between the two. Second, I never used GridSearchCV but I think it should get a "space" and not final values so it can search for the best hyper parameters.

Comment: @Eran Moshe I יhave added the R cod. note that the python classifier get the exact same train and test as r.

Comment: @Eran Moshe I am supposed to get same result with thous king of hyper parameters (or close results).

Comment: Without the actual data, it is difficult to reproduce it. Can you provide your data, or can you reproduce the same behavior using easily accessible public datasets?

Comment: @coffeinjunky I can't provide the data, but I will use a public dataset and update my Q.

Comment: I had similar experience recently. Any insights on this so far?